# SQL discrepancy between addition of columns and summing of a columns with NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sum, set-theory

When I add two columns `v` and `w` together the results of the rows give `NULL` if one or both summand are `NULL`. This makes sense.  But if I sum over the column with `SUM(v)` there will be a numeric result even there are `NULL`s. Is this due to practical convience? Or is there a theoretical justification?

Here is an example to clarify (MySQL and sqlite):

```
CREATE TABLE x0 (
  id    INTEGER 
, v     DOUBLE
, w     DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO x0 VALUES
  (1,    1,     1)
, (2,    1,     1)
, (3, NULL,     1)
, (4,    1,  NULL)
, (5, NULL,  NULL)
;

-- NULL if summand is NULL
SELECT v+w
FROM x0
;
-- v+w
-- 2
-- 2
-- \N
-- \N
-- \N

-- NULL if summand is NULL
SELECT id, v+w, SUM(v+w)
FROM x0
GROUP BY id
;
-- id   v+w SUM(v+w)
-- 1    2   2
-- 2    2   2
-- 3    \N  \N
-- 4    \N  \N
-- 5    \N  \N


-- There is numeric results even if some summands are NULL    
SELECT SUM(v), SUM(w)
FROM x0
;
-- SUM(v)   SUM(w)
-- 3        3
```

Comment: SQL is far from having a sound and consistent theoretical foundation.  Just accept that is how the standard defines the operations.  "Theoretically" the value should be `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`, because `NULL` values are indeterminate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I thought that SQL is based on set theory. So, for convience it seems to leave mathematical thoroughness in some cases, for example, using functions like `SUM`.

Comment: Standard SQL simply ignores/removes NULLs within aggregation functions. Otherwise you would have to use COALESCE on NULLable columns like `MIN(COALESCE(mycolumn, 9999999)` and then it's hard to know if a returned 9999999 is actually the lowest value or the NULL replacement.

Comment: @giordano . . . *relational algebra* is based on set theory.  SQL is loosely based on relational algebra.  You can think of it more as a mongrel inspired by relational algebra but created by a committee and despite all that happens to do a lot of useful things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ISO/IEC 9075:1992 Database Language SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) says in section 6.5 (<set function specification>), General Rules, 1) b):

> let TX be the single-column table that is the
>   result of applying the <value expression> to each row of T
>   **and eliminating null values**.

And that's all it says. So aggregate functions must ignore NULLs, but, officially, there is no justification.

This behaviour goes back to the first SQL implementations (IBM System R, Oracle V2), where the designers probably thought this would be a good idea. And later, nobody wanted to break backwards compatibility.

In this aspect, as in others, [SQL's handling of NULL values](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) is inconsistent, and sometimes not portable.

Answer (score 0):

this is normal  . you must manage with a  proper function the null value

eg in mysql

```
 SELECT id, ifnull(v,0)+infnull(w,0), SUM(ifnull(v,0)+infnull(w,0))
 FROM x0
 GROUP BY id
```

http://rustyrazorblade.com/2006/09/mysql-number-null-null/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-null-values.htm
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html